# Issues with R packages install inside Postgres Docker Image

Tags: r, postgresql

I have a postgres Dockerfile that works perfectly fine. I managed to install R-3.3.3 inside the image via the Dockerfile and found the containers from this work correctly. However when I tried to install packages via the following entries, the image creation succeeds however the container from it exits right away with normal status. Here are the new entries I added that changed the behavior. What am I missing?

```
  RUN   R -e "install.packages('devtools',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
      && R -e "install.packages('RPostgreSQL',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')" \
      && R -e "install.packages('hash',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')" \
      && R -e "install.packages('nloptr',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')" \
      && R -e "install.packages('DBI',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')" \
      && R -e "install.packages('Rcpp',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')" \
      && R -e "install.packages('BH',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
```

Comment: While, I do understand a container would exit with 0 status if there is no command. However I have this and have tested it to work correctly. Why only after adding the above lines (a layer somewhere above), should make such a difference?  EXPOSE 5432
CMD ["postgres"]

Answer (score 0):

It all worked fine. Something incorrect with the Docker file. After I got this together, it all started working fine.

```
RUN   apt-get install -y --auto-remove \
      default-jdk \
      libcurl4-openssl-dev \
      build-essential \
      gfortran \
      zlib1g \
      zlib1g-dev \
      libbz2-dev \
      liblzma-dev \
      libpcre3-dev \
      postgresql-9.6-plr \
      libpq-dev \
      libssl-dev \
  &&  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/apt/methods/bzip2 apt-get -y install wget \
  &&  wget -O /R-3.3.3.tar.gz https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.3.3.tar.gz \
  &&  cd / \
  &&  gunzip /R-3.3.3.tar.gz \
  &&  tar xvf R-3.3.3.tar \
  &&  cd R-3.3.3 \
  &&  ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-readline=no --with-x=no \
  && make \
  && make install \
  && R -e "install.packages('devtools',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')" \
  && R -e "install.packages('RPostgreSQL',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')" \
  && R -e "install.packages('hash',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')" \
  && R -e "install.packages('nloptr',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')" \
  && R -e "install.packages('DBI',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')" \
  && R -e "install.packages('Rcpp',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')" \
  && R -e "install.packages('BH',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')" \
  && cd .. \
  && rm  R-3.3.3.tar \
  && rm -rf R-3.3.3 \
  && apt purge -y --auto-remove \
         default-jdk \
         libssl-dev \
         libpq-dev \
         libpcre3-dev \
         liblzma-dev \
         libbz2-dev \
         zlib1g-dev \
         libcurl4-openssl-dev \
         build-essential \
         wget \
   && rm -f /tmp/Rtmp* \
   && apt-get -y autoremove
```